How to Perform XML String Transformation and XPath Extraction in a Non-Camel Web Service?
I’m working on a web service that processes SOAP responses (in XML format), and I need to:

Take the original payload.
Perform conditional replacements on the XML content:


If the body contains the string "is:folio", replace it with "is:ApplicantDataFolio".
Otherwise, replace the first occurrence of "folio" with a namespace declaration, followed by replacing all occurrences of "folio" with "is:ApplicantDataFolio".


Extract a specific XML element (ApplicantDataFolio) using XPath after the transformations are applied.

Here's what I want to achieve:
In Camel, the transformation would look like this:
<convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
<choice>
    <when>
        <simple>${body} contains 'is:folio'</simple>
        <setBody>
            <simple>${body.replaceAll("is:folio", "is:ApplicantDataFolio")}</simple>
        </setBody>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <setBody>
            <simple>${body.replaceFirst("folio", "is:ApplicantDataFolio xmlns:is='urn:digimarc.com:imaging'")}</simple>
        </setBody>
        <setBody>
            <simple>${body.replaceAll("folio", "is:ApplicantDataFolio")}</simple>
        </setBody>
    </otherwise>
</choice>

<setBody>
    <xpath>//*[local-name()='ApplicantDataFolio']</xpath>
</setBody>


Right now, when I try to send my payload, I get and Unmarshalling Error:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"urn:digimarc.com:imaging", local:"folio"). Expected elements are &lt;{urn:l1id.com:ImageServer}folio>,&lt;{urn:l1id.com:ImageServer}replaceDirective> </faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

My goal:
I need to replicate this transformation logic without using Apache Camel, but instead with plain Java in a non-Camel web service context.
